# Hiding a node in ExtJs 4.1 TreePanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

How can we hide some of the nodes in ExtJs 4.1 TreePanel based on some condition?
We can hide node in ExtJs 3.4 by doing this:

```
tree.getRootNode().cascade(function() { // descends into child nodes
    if(this.attributes['status'] == 100) { // test this node
        this.getUI().hide() // hide this node
    }
})
```

But this method is no longer supported in ExtJs 4.1.

Comment: if you remove the records from the store they will not show up in the tree. You could filter the store if you need to dynamically show and hide on command.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [topic about this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?142704-Show-Hide-of-the-tree-node-in-ExtJS-4) on Sencha's forum. It seems that this is not supported but have workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

For ExtJS 6, for example, when read config is false, hide the node:

```
hideItemsReadFalse: function () {
    var me = this,
        items = me.getReferences().treelistRef.itemMap;


        for(var i in items){
            if(items[i].config.node.data.read == false){
                items[i].destroy();
            }
        }
}
```

Root:

```
{
    "text": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "text": "Atualização",
            "iconCls": "x-fa fa-list",
            "children": [
                {
                    "leaf":true,
                    "text": "Empresas",
                    "module": "empresas",
                    "iconCls": "x-fa fa-building",
                    "read": false
                },
                {
                    "leaf":true,
                    "text": "Produtos",
                    "module": "produtos",
                    "iconCls": "x-fa fa-cubes",
                    "read": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```